# How to create an online Bottle server accessible from any system?

Tags: python-3.x, server, bottle

The project I'm doing requires a server. But, with Bottle I can create only a localhost server. I want to be able to access it anywhere. What do I use? I know about pythonanywhere.com, but I'm not sure as to how to go about it.

Comment: This question probably belongs on serverfault. Try searching for free cloud hosting services. Or just research on using pythonanywhere.com.

Answer (score 2):

On PythonAnywhere, all you need to do is:

- Sign up for an account, and log in.
- Go to the "Web" tab
- Click the "Add a new web app" button
- Select "Bottle"
- Select the Python version you want to use
- Specify where you want your code files to be

...and then you'll have a bottle server up and running on the Internet, with simple "Hello world" code behind it.  You can then change that to do whatever you want.